# Windows batch file replace text issue

Tags: batch-file

I have this code to replace some text in JS file:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=showLog: true"
set "replace=showLog: false"
set "textfile=globalsDebugTest.js"
set "newfile=new.js"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"
```

The problem with this script is that it **adds a line number** in every new line.
I just want to replace this string: *"showLog: true"* with this: *"showLog: false"*.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: This can be fragile in batch, there are lots of command line tools that can do this (FART). As for the line numbers `/n` explicitly asks for a line number ... (see `findstr /?`)

Comment: `findstr /?
  /N         Prints the line number before each line that matches.`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%h in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
```

(note the addition of a `tokens=` phrase, `delims` is assigned `:` and the loop *metavariable* is changed to `h`.)

adding the `tokens=` means the metavariable `h` receives the number before the delimiter (colon) and `i` the remainder of the line after the colon. This keeps the changes on one line.

Another option would be to simply drop the `/n` from the `findstr` which will have the consequence of removing all empty lines from the output.

Comment: Excuse me. Why do you use _metavariable_ term? All DOS commands documentation I know use the _replaceable parameter_ term instead, like [this one from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true), or [this one](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html). Just curious...

Comment: @Aacini: old habit from newsgroup alt.msdos.batch[.nt] - term commonly used there. Actually, I'm not convinced it's strictly being used correctly, but then DOS is a term with a strict definition which is ignored by Microsoft and even moreso by batchies, much to the annoyance of those that insist that it be called "Command Prompt" - another generic term hijacked to mean a particular windows app.